# How do I fetch data from database through php to javascript variable?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a jQuery UI datepicker. I want to send data to that function. I used `.post` function to fetch data from database as "data" through a PHP file. I am unable to access the data as the data returned to inside the .post function. I want it to the out side variable `dat` so that I can use it. Actually the data are the dates which are to be disable.

My code:

```
$(function () {
    var dat = "";
    var unavailableDates = ["10-5-2013", "14-5-2011", "15-5-2011"];
    var dt = "id=1";
    $.post("fetch.php", dt, function (data) {});
    dat = data;

    function enableFirday(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [((day == 6 || day == 5 || day == 3) && $.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0), ''];
    }
    $("#d").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: enableFirday
    });
});
```

Inside the function there is a variable `unavailableDates` in the 3rd line. I want to fetch some date from my database and keep in that variable.

I thought I can use `.post` to fetch data from database so that I can use. But data are returned from PHP file and not copying to the variable `dat`. That are returned from PHP file can be used inside the .post function but not out side. How can I get the data to outside of the `.post` function. Please help me for this. It is very necessary to fetch data in my project.

Comment: You can use a hidden input field and store the values from Database in that. Use `getElementbyId` to fetch data to `javascript` variable.

Comment: Just so you are aware, stubbing out the callback like `function(data) {}` only scopes the `data` variable to that empty block you defined for the function and so the following assignment of `dat = data` will always evaluate to `dat = undefined` unless you set `data` somewhere globally (which is still not a good thing). @MarcB's answer says the root of your issue best I just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX calls (your `$.post()`) ASYNCHRONOUS. Your JS code will run the .post() function, then continue onwards immediately. Unless you've got an insanely fast network link, it is virtually impossible for a response to come back from the AJAX call and populate the `data` variable.

That's why AJAX calls come with a callback handler, which JS will invoke when a response comes in from the server, so your code should be

```
var dat;
$.post(url, dt, function(data) {
    dat = data;
    enableFirday(); // or whatever your code should do once you get a response.
});
```